# Nginx Django csrf_token get 502 error invalid header

Tags: django, nginx, pinax, uwsgi, django-csrf

I have a Django site developed using Pinax. When I deploy it in apache+mod_wsgi, it works fine. But when I deploy it in nginx+uwsgi, it nearly works fine, but the page includes a `{% csrf_token %}` tag. The crashed page dose not display a Django error page, but displays an Nginx 502 error page. The Nginx error log is:

> 2012/06/08 09:11:59 [error] 30224#0: *79 upstream sent invalid header
>   while reading response header from upstream, client: 211.142.12.3,
>   server: mysite.com, request: "GET /discuss/ HTTP/1.1", upstream:
>   "uwsgi://127.0.0.1:9001", host: "mysite.com", referrer:
>   "http://mysite.com/"

uwsgi displays:

> {address space usage: 42319872 bytes/40MB} {rss usage: 22573056
>   bytes/21MB} [pid: 21398|app: 0|req: 1/3] 110.178.82.221 () {42 vars in
>   988 bytes} [Fri Jun  8 18:27:01 2012] GET /discuss/ => generated 31139
>   bytes in 2306 msecs (HTTP/1.1 200) 5 headers in 358 bytes (1 switches
>   on core 0)

The error occurs on a GET request, not a POST request. I tested this - when I delete the `csrf_token` token from the template, it's OK. So, there must be a relationship between the token and the error, not anything else.

What's going on?

Comment: view codes are very simple: get model, render_to_response.

Comment: Shouldn't there be some `POST` process, as the `csrf_token` in the page.

Comment: Nginx cannot handle the HTTP headers generated by uWSGI,I think the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, it's solved. I had installed uwsgi by compiling the source. Now I delete that version, and reinstall it using `pip install uwsgi`, and everything is fine!